# I have application developed in C# which are getting the values from ODBC . I run my application with help of Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-x64

I have application developed in C# which are getting the values from ODBC . I run my application with help of Scheduler  in windows server 2008 it is working fine, when System is On, but scheduler is not working when System is log off.

Although I check the Properties 
1. Run whether User is logged or not
2. I  given the Username and Password of local system.
3. In services.msc the task scheduler service  startuptype is automatic and logon as local-system.

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

You need to create the tasks so that they run under the local system.